How to apply a delay to Excel macro
I have a list of URLs in Excel that I have to open asynchronously otherwise the server will ban me.
Sub OpenHyperLinks()
Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "OpenHyperlinksInExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
xHyperlink.Follow
Next
End Sub

This macro opens all the URLs at the same time (and there are over 1000 of them) and consequently causes a system crash. I need this, or a similar macro, to open the URLs one at a time with a delay of, for example, 10 seconds.
I can't find a solution. I've tried them all, but I can't get it to work.

You could add Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03") after xHyperlink.Follow in order to pause the code for three seconds. Maybe that is sufficient.

You tried all the solutions? like what?

Use a Timer?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function

@Solar Mike:  If the OP truly exhausted every possible solution, logically there shouldn't be any more solutions left to try.  SCNR :-)

@Storax "Like what?" was meant to elicit examples in the original questions to show what the OP had tried so they could be improved / corrected.

@Solar Mike: I know. I just could not resist to make this remark :-)

To apply a delay within a VBA macro, you can use the Application.Wait  method.
Using Application.Wait
The Application.Wait method pauses the execution of the macro for a specified amount of time. It takes the form Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue), where
TimeValue is the delay duration you want in hours, minutes, and seconds.
Here's an example of how to use Application.Wait to introduce a delay of 5 seconds in your VBA macro:
Sub DelayExample()
    ' Your code before the delay
    
    ' Pause execution for 5 seconds
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    
    ' Your code after the delay
End Sub

Application.Wait is simple to use for basic delays but it's limited to whole seconds.
Update: You could insert Applciation.Wait in your code like
For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
    
    xHyperlink.Follow
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Next

Another approach could be to use sleep
Option Explicit

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub delayExample()
    
    Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink, xTitleId
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    
    xTitleId = "OpenHyperlinksInExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    ' Pause execution for 5 seconds
    For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
        xHyperlink.Follow
        Sleep 5000   ' Sleep for ~5s
    Next
End Sub


Unfortunately it doesn't work, maybe I'm wrong in matching your code to mine? Could you give me an example by entering my code? Thank you

I edited the poast but apart from that just to write it doesn't work is not a really helpful description. What excatly does not work?

Use the delay subroutine below -
 Sub sbDelay(delay As Long) 
     Dim i As Long
     For i = 1 To delay 
         DoEvents 
     Next i  
 End Sub

This has the advantage of using DoEvents to create the delay which means you can move around in Excel or a browser while the Excel waits (ie it is non-modal). You will need to experiment with the number used to call it, start with 100,000.
